# WPF - wrapping stackpanel

Tags: wpf, stackpanel, word-wrap

I have a panel with Width = 1400 and it contains smaller Panels with Width = 700. If the screen is at full width the smaller panels should be displayed in 2's per row otherwise it should wrap and a vertical scrollbar should appear.

With the below code the contents are wrapped but no scrollbar:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="1400">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="body" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxHeight="700" Width="{Binding ElementName=body, Path=ViewportWidth}">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="700" Height="400">

            </Border>

            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="700" Height="400">

            </Border>

            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="700" Height="400">

            </Border>

            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="700" Height="400">

            </Border>
        </WrapPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Suggested solutions didn't work. My current code:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="#FFEAEEFC">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="body" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <WrapPanel Margin="10" MaxWidth="1400">
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="700" Height="400">

                </Border>

                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="700" Height="400">

                </Border>

                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="700" Height="400">

                </Border>

                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="700" Height="400">

                </Border>
            </WrapPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a fixed width in your main stackpanel that prevent the scrollviewer to work.
Removing Width="1400" should work.

Edit:
Remove the stackpanel or change it with a DockPanel. The content of the stackpanel is not resized according to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the xaml like below to achieve it.

```
  <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
        <WrapPanel MaxWidth="200">
            <Border Width="100" Height="70" Background="Blue"/>
            <Border Width="100" Height="70" Background="Green"/>
            <Border Width="100" Height="70" Background="Red"/>
            <Border Width="100" Height="70" Background="Yellow"/>
            <Border Width="100" Height="70" Background="Blue"/>
            <Border Width="100" Height="70" Background="Black"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Also in a typical databinding scenario, you might need to use a ListBox/ItemsControl as the container and set WrapPanel as its ItemsPanelTemplate and databind your collection to the ListBox.